# Create multiple countdowns in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and i am trying to implement a simple timer.For example i have one button and every time i click this button, a dialog shows up and i can set the time.

This time should then be displayed on the same activity, where the button is.
I am fairly new to android and i have only a button on my main activity.

My Questions now : How can i dynamicly add "countdowns" to my main_activity.Lets say maximum is 3.Is there something like a `countdown class` already or does `TimePicker` this for me ?

Comment: Please just search your question on google/stackoverflow before posting it because it is so much easier and less time consuming. (Especially because you are a beginner, every question you have is already answered somewhere)

Comment: You want to use the [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code runs a timer for 30 seconds. If you want the user to choose time, you can use an EditText to get the time from user and put it instead of `30000` in below code.

```
final CountDownTimer timer;
    timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerText.setText("seconds remaining: " + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            timerText.setText("done!");
        }
    };
```